# Занесение в раздел реестра данных при инсталляции программы

Tags: c#, visual-studio, реестр, windowsinstaller, setup

Во время инсталляции msi-пакета, исполняется файл sharpTest.exe

[image]

Его свойства:

[image]
<sub>(источник: [userapi.com](https://pp.userapi.com/c638922/v638922206/2c2c6/WxTS2-Szn_4.jpg))</sub>

Весь код sharpTest иполняется исправно, кроме, собственно, создания нового ключа в реестре:

[image]

Однако, если запустить этот файл после инсталляции вручную, то новый ключ в разделе создастся.

Подскажите почему новый ключ реестра не создается в процессе инсталляции?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Думаю, проблема в том, что инсталлятор запускается от имени администратора или системы. Соответственно его `CurrentUser` не тот, что вы ожидаете.

Если значение имеет глобальный смысл, возможно, его нужно писать в HKML. Если нет, пусть программа, запущенная от имени юзера, создаёт этот ключ в HKCU сама (для каждого юзера на машине).

Comment: Попробовал вместо CurrentUser создать ключ в LocalMachine -- сработало.

Comment: Мне нужно исключить возможность записи в реестр какими-либо способами, кроме как при установке. Ведь в другом случае как удостовериться, что мою программу установили, а не просто скопировали с другого компьютера?

Comment: @salkcid ну, реестр вам в этом деле тоже не особо поможет.

Comment: @D-side, а что поможет?

Comment: @salkcid по-хорошему, ничего. Но разработчики DRM упорно пытаются доказать обратное и находятся в постоянной войне с пиратами, а устройство своих продуктов по очевидным причинам скрывают, и оно очевидно далеко от простого. Последнее из актуального, что я слышал, использовало какую-то хитрую обфускацию и шифрованное общение с сервером системы при каждом запуске. Такого калибра вещи.

Comment: @salkcid: Никак не получится. Юзер на своей машине — царь и бог, он может всё. Вы можете лишь немного помешать ему. И надеяться, что ему скорее надоест, чем он вскроет вашу систему.